# How can I create a menu entry for GRUB which boots Ubuntu in console mode?

Tags: grub2

It would be easier if I can create an entry in the GRUB menu to boot between GUI and console.

I don't want X to start sometimes. Does GRUB support that kind of feature?

Comment: See [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029350/348964) to [Add GRUB menu item to boot into terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/1029339/348964)

Answer (score 2):

I searched around a little and came across [this blog-post](http://ubuntuguide.net/add-a-grub2-entry-for-ubuntu-booting-into-consolecommand-line), however I'm not really sure I like the method used. Perhaps you could combine those instructions with the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) under the section for Configuring GRUB 2 --> Custom Menu Entries and get a working solution. Hope this helps!