# Add GRUB menu item to boot into terminal

Tags: 16.04, boot, command-line, dual-boot, grub2

OK, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

Have a separate menu option in GRUB, so that I can select it and boot straight into the command line - that is: without a desktop manager, but leaving the existing menu item (to boot Ubuntu as usual) intact.

I've looked into `/etc/default/grub` but there seems nothing to do there. And also `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` which is auto-generated, so I don't think it would be a good idea to edit it directly.

How should I go about it? Any idea?

---

**Update:** The existing answer (suggesting that this question was a duplicate) was obsolete. For the correct solution, please see the accepted answer below, which works beautifully. (at least for 16.04+ as it seems)

Comment: I think the best place for that is in the `/etc/grub.d` adding you custom menu entry there, please read the `README` file in there!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add console/text booting mode to grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158551/add-console-text-booting-mode-to-grub-menu)

Comment: @PerlDuck  I know this answer, and just tried it, but it didn't work for me. It boots in the GUI as usual.

Comment: Yes, that's because it lacks a crucial point for recent Ubuntu versions.

Comment: @PerlDuck I'm running 16.04 - I hope it qualifies as "recent".

Comment: I hope so as well. I tested my solution with 16.10, 17.04, and 17.10. The point is the `systemd.unit=multi-user.target` parameter in the `linux` line. I described that in my answer.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/859630/how-to-start-ubuntu-in-console-mode and from that: https://superuser.com/questions/1106174/boot-ubuntu-16-04-into-command-line-do-not-start-gui/1139020#1139020  I just tried the 3 as runlevel in place of quiet splash and did boot to terminal and terminal login. But starting gui with old startx gave strange results. Do not think I got full correct gui.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### One

Open the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and find the section that boots your "regular" Ubuntu.

For me this is:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-b8f25f1e-a169-4aaa-9f05-90e49359d865' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  b8f25f1e-a169-4aaa-9f05-90e49359d865
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b8f25f1e-a169-4aaa-9f05-90e49359d865
        fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-39-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=b8f25f1e-a169-4aaa-9f05-90e49359d865 ro  
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-39-generic
}
```

Copy that section to a new file, say `textmode.txt`.

### Two

Go to `/etc/grub.d` and create (or edit) the file `40_custom`.

Copy the following "header" to the file:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
```

Add the menuentry from `textmode.txt` to the file but change some values (see below):

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu (text mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-b8f25f1e-a169-4aaa-9f05-90e49359d865' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  b8f25f1e-a169-4aaa-9f05-90e49359d865
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b8f25f1e-a169-4aaa-9f05-90e49359d865
        fi
        linux   /vmlinuz root=UUID=b8f25f1e-a169-4aaa-9f05-90e49359d865 systemd.unit=multi-user.target ro
        initrd  /initrd.img
}
```

The values that must be changed are:

- The *menuentry* text: change it from `'Ubuntu'` to `'Ubuntu (text mode)'` (or whatever you like to appear in the menu)
- The `linux` line: change it to `linux   /vmlinuz root=UUID=... systemd.unit=multi-user.target ro`. Make sure the UUID stays the same.
- The `initrd` line: change it to `/initrd.img`

Make sure you have symlinks in your `/` directory from `/vmlinuz` and `/initrd.img` to the current versions. This is the default, anyway.

### Three

Run

```
sudo update-grub
```

The difference between this approach and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/161119/504066) to a very similar question is that in recent versions of Ubuntu the line

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-31-generic root=UUID=... ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

needs to be replaced with

```
linux   /vmlinuz root=UUID=... systemd.unit=multi-user.target ro
```

I'm not sure what *recent* actually means but I guess it's 16.04 when *systemd* was introduced.

Comment: My friend, you're *awesome*. It worked! :) The trick was that `systemd.unit=multi-user-target` part. Now, as a sidenote, I had to leave the `linux` and `initrd` parts as they were, because it complained that it couldn't find an image at `/vmlinuz`, etc. But other than that, simply great. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. I also once noticed that the symlink `vmlinuz → boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-39-generic` was missing but after some time (and updates) it appeared. Perhaps it only comes to existence when multiple kernel images are installed.

Comment: hmm, you maybe have a point. Who knows.. Mine is a super fresh install, so chances are all it can see is just one kernel image.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22 LTS `linux` and `initrd` paths should be `/boot/vmlinuz` and `/boot/initrd.img` respectively. Both are symlinks to latest kernel in the same directory. The menu item will break after few updates if you leave specific versions in place, i.e. `/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-38-generic`. `ls -Al /boot/` and compare `vmlinuz` with `vmlinuz.old` to understand the issue.

Comment: Also `resume=UUID=xxx` parameter needs to be removed if you have it because you will not be able to resume hibernated graphical session in text mode.